# React parse text to html markup

Tags: reactjs

I use React JS, and I want to make a universal component, to show message for user. Like as at image: [image]

I want to send text like as this : `"Lorem ipsum ["Link"](url) Lorem ipsum **Strong text**"`. How I may parse this with JavaScript? I can imagine how to implement this, but I would not like to reinvent my wheel, maybe there are some ready-made and elegant solutions?

Comment: You can use [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) to parse markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Markdown component for React. Try [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
ReactDom.render(
    <ReactMarkdown>
        Lorem ipsum [link](url) <br />
        Lorem ipsum **Strong text**
    </ReactMarkdown>,
    yourElement
)
```